# HUD background changed to black and can't use wine

Tags: unity, hud

I am new to Ubuntu. After updating 12.04, HUD background changed to black instead of transparent and can't use **Wine** and **ccc** anymore.

Then I tried GNOME but only the wallpaper appeared and can't do anything. 
I am using ASUS ATI Radeon 3450/512MB graphic card. Before updating Ubuntu, I installed ATI driver from [amd.com](http://www.amd.com/us/Pages/AMDHomePage.aspx).

Could it be the graphic card driver problem? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I had a black icon set installed. So, all I did was change my icons and I was able to see my applications and such. Also you should still be able to select applications or whatever by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, that will highlight Unity trigger, then type in the desired application, use your directional button to navigate, and tap down twice, then hit enter. That should open your application.

**Tip**: If you don't have **MyUnity** installed, I would suggest installing it. And, **Ubuntu Tweak** is another great tool to help you tweak HUD settings. If this doesn't help, and it's a graphics card issue, then you'll have to get advise from someone that's knowledgeable on specific hardware.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to use unity HUD and other applications except wine's and ccc. And I installed Ubuntu Tweak but it didn't help me. My only solution was reinstalling ATI driver. And now it is all going well again :). Also, after graphic driver installed, Terminal window background forced to transparent and I can't change it back. that's weired.